# Best way to run scheduled tasks in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

What would be the best way of running scheduled tasks in asp.net 5, mvc 6 app.  It will be ideal if I could use the built-in dependency injection in scheduled tasks. I will be running this application under dnx.

I know this question have been ask for earlier versions of asp.net but those solutions might not be the best way in asp.net 5. As it has a different runtime.

Comment: First of all, maybe you could disclose why you need httpcontext in scheduled task?

Comment: Sometimes i need Url or hostName to run conditions in a multi tenant environment.

Comment: [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx), [The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/).